# SharePoint 2010 Site Collection Upgrade Required

Tags: cumulative-update, configuration-wizard

I just installed the CU onto our SP 2010 environment. The CU and config wizard went through fine and central admin came back with No action required. This morning I saw the central admin and it says Upgrade Required. Ran the stsadm -o localupgradestatus and found 2 site collections needing upgrade. I know that in SP 2013 we have a command that can upgrade it.

Upgrade-SPSite http:///sites/testsite

I would like to know what is the command that does the same in SP 2010. How to fix these 2 site collections?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2011/05/24/you-must-manually-run-psconfig-after-installing-sharepoint-2010-patches/

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, that has already been run on the farm. Its only these 2 site collections that needs upgrade.

Comment: Review your PSConfig log files and your missing server side dependencies health analyzer alert.  There may be some custom or missing feature inside these sites that is preventing upgrade.  You could also run Test-SPContentDatabase which checks for issues for upgrade to SP2013.  That may also identify issues preventing upgrade to the 2010 CU.